# Android ListView flickering/not refreshing properly when scrolling

Tags: android, listview

I'm an android newbie trying out my first project (API level 10). I'm downloading json data in my ListActivity, populating it into a local sqlite db and displaying it with a custom CursorAdapter.  I have only TextViews in my layout now but will be changing that, thus the custom CursorAdapter.  Everything seems to work, the db is populated and the data is displayed but it flickers when scrolling the list and I'm getting overlaying text / unclean refreshes. Any help would be appreciated.  I've tried using a "ViewHolder" in my ItemAdapter but it did not help and then removed it.  I have no background specified..

My Code:

```
public class ItemList extends ListActivity {

    private static ItemDBAdapter dao;
    private static ProgressDialog dialog;
    private static Cursor ItemCursor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_Item_list);
        getListView().setSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true);
        dao = new ItemDBAdapter(this);
        dao.open();
        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Download", "Downloading");
        load();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_Item_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
      if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        dialog = null;
      }
      super.onDestroy();
    }



    private class DownloadDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
          String success = "false";
          String response = "";

          for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
              HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
              InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

              BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
              String s = "";
              while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                response += s;
              }
              JSONArray Items = new JSONArray(response);
              dao.saveAll(Items);


            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
          success = "true";

          return success;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO: check if internet failed, not all data loaded, etc...
            dialog.dismiss();
            fillData();
            if (result == "true") {

            }
        }
      }

      public void load() {
        DownloadDataTask task = new DownloadDataTask();
        task.execute(new String[] { "http://247.85.45.12:3000/Item/index.json" });
      }

      public void fillData() {
          ItemCursor = dao.getAll();
          ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter(this, ItemCursor);
          setListAdapter(adapter);
          startManagingCursor(ItemCursor);

      }
}

public class ItemAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private final Context context;
private int NAME, ADDRESS, PHONE, URL;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
public ItemAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    this.context = context;
    NAME = c.getColumnIndex(ItemDBAdapter.KEY_NAME);
    URL = c.getColumnIndex(ItemDBAdapter.KEY_URL);
    ADDRESS = c.getColumnIndex(ItemDBAdapter.KEY_ADDRESS);
    PHONE = c.getColumnIndex(ItemDBAdapter.KEY_PHONE);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    if (view != null) {
    TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView url = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.url);
    TextView address = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.address);
    TextView phone = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.phone);

    name.setText(cursor.getString(NAME));
    url.setText(cursor.getString(URL));
    address.setText(cursor.getString(ADDRESS));
    phone.setText(cursor.getString(PHONE));
    }

}
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Item_item, null);        

    return v;
}
```

}

Activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

List Item Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/url"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I've changed the ListView width and Linear Layout width to "match_parent"

```
 <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

I've noticed that the area's that have unclean refreshes and overlayed text are the unused areas.  This fixed the problem. Couldn't see the problem on virtual device at all but is very evident on high res galaxy s3

Answer (score -1):

try to call

```
getListView.setCacheColorHint(...);
```

with background color of your items or 0 if there is no such color (it will disable caching). If you have no background at all, not even a window background, that might be the problem too.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Ive already tried that before via xml..but i dont specify any background in my layouts..its default

Comment: You can add android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" to your Listview.